# Down sides/Cons to Dual-Sided USB connectors?

Tags: usb, connector

Do dual-sided USB connectors have inferior qualities compared with single-sided e.g. less mechanically reliable or reduced speed?

[image: Image of dual-sided USB]

From reading [Why do USB connectors only fit one way?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26294/why-do-usb-connectors-only-fit-one-way) it seems that this is breaking the USB specification but I have used them without problems in the past and they seemed quite robust.

Comment: Just an observation -- reversibility was designed into the (relatively new) C connector, avoid these sort of kludges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Do non-standard connectors suck compared to standard connectors?*

Completely depends on the quality of the connector and **how non-standard it is**. Hack-y solutions result in hack-y results. Have fun trying to figure it out as no one really knows.